# How to run Queue_Classic (or any) rake task automatically on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 3.2 app that uses the Queue_Classic gem, and is deployed on Heroku.

Currently my queued jobs are not being processed, unless I run `heroku run rake qc:work` in the command line.

I have added a Procfile containing the following:

```
worker:  bundle exec rake qc:work
```

but still no processing of the queue unless I run `heroku run rake qc:work` manually.

What am I missing?

This app uses Unicorn, could this be having an impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I came up with the following solution.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, or how it will behave as we scale web processes etc, but it's working for now.

I set up unicorn as usual, including

```
#Procfile
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

then i added the following config

```
#unicorn.rb
worker_processes 3 
timeout 30

@qc_pid = nil

before_fork do |server, worker|
  @qc_pid ||= spawn( "bundle exec rake qc:work" )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically your workers run independently from your web processes. To run a worker, you need to set your process formation to run 1 worker:

```
$ heroku scale worker=1
```

Answer (score 0):

*Be sure to include queue_classic and queue_classic/tasks in your primary Rakefile.*